# Screen page does not show anything from React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm working on the project and my productScreen.js is empty despite I have a code inside.

I'm following one of the tutorial and not sure what I did wrong.[image]

My productScreen.js codes

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card  } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import products from '../products';
function ProductScreen({match}) {
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id == match.params.id)
    console.log('wfw')
    return (

        <div>
            
            <Link to='/' className = 'btn btn-light my-3'> Go Back</Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

My App.js that calling ProductScreen

```
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

/*import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen' */

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div>
    <Header/>
    <main className='py-3'>
      <Container>
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomeScreen} />
        <Route path='/product/:id' component={ProductScreen} />
      </Container>
    </main>
    <Footer/>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I try to use console.log() and if print anything but does not show anything, but it doesn't give me error that it can't find ProductScreen.js file. So since they are able to find ProductScreen.js I guessing the code in ProductScreen.js is the problem?

Any suggestion to debug this issue?

https://github.com/williamkwon97/CRT-Commerce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the project on github. 
The problem is a typo in `Product.js` file: 
there is a redirect to `/products` while the router responds on `/product` (see the last letter).

It is a good option to use costants in order to avoid simple mistakes for endpoints. 
`export const ENPDOINT_PRODUCT = 'product'` 
and then 
`import { ENDPOINT_PRODUCT } from './costants'`

---

And secondary, in productScreen.js file the component 'react-router-bootstrap' exports LinkContainer so the code should look like this:

```
...
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'
...

// inside return function
<LinkContainer to="/" className = "btn btn-light my-3">
    <Button>Go Back</Button>
</LinkContainer>
...
```

Cheers